# Apache Camel Karaf Mandatory header ignored

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have a route with a rest put call. And I need to declare a mandatory header in this call. But I'm not getting it from blueprint.xml. Even without the declared header, the answer is 200. Here's my route xml:

```
<restConfiguration bindingMode="json"
   clientRequestValidation="true" component="jetty"
   enableCORS="true" host="{{rest.endpoint.host}}" port="{{rest.endpoint.port}}">
   <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
```

`enter code here`

What am I forgetting or putting wrong? Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your route from your question, what you have there is rest configuration.

You can use `filter` to check if header is missing then set proper response body and headers and use `stop` to early out when the header is missing from the request.

Heres how in Java-DSL

```java
from("direct:needsHeader")
    .filter(header("requiredHeader").isNull())
        .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(400))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/plain"))
        .setBody().constant("Missing requiredHeader!")
        .log("${body}")
        .stop()
    .end()
    .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(200))
    .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/plain"))
    .setBody().simple("requiredHeader value: ${headers.requiredHeader}")
    .log("${body}");
```

Haven't used blueprints myself much but above is probably fairly easy to implement with blueprints as well.